# jQuery AJAX dataType:"json" can't use it ... just use Array instead

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

Originally I was trying to send a Javascript JSON Object to a PHP page, without success.
Using the following test code:

```
var testobj = {
  "test1":"test1data",
  "test2":"test2data",
  "test3":"test3data"
};
alert(testobj.test1);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxtest.php",
  dataType: "json",
  data: testobj
})
  .error(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Error: " + msg );
  })
  .success(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Success: " + msg );
  });
```

Never sends the data, and always returns an error.

Removing the 'dataType' attribute or defining it as anything other than 'json' returns 'success', but still no data is sent.

I can use the exact same Object code as the 'data:' value and it DOES get sent, but not when I use the JSON Object.

So I send an Array, instead:

```
var testobj = new Array();
testobj = {
  "test1":"test1data",
  "test2":"test2data",
  "test3":"test3data"
};
alert(testobj.test1);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajaxtest.php",
  data: testobj
})
  .error(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Error: " + msg );
  })
  .success(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Success: " + msg );
  });
```

Exactly the same code, except (a) I defined the variable as an Array instead of a JSON Object and (b) I removed the 'dataType' attribute from the .ajax call.

Grab the Array elements on the target page using the $_POST array.

I never much cared for JSON as a method for passing data, anyway, so this doesn't exactly worry me. But I do wonder about the current state of jQuery (v.1.9.1)

Is there something wrong with my JSON construction? What's the deal with sending a JSON Object via jQuery AJAX? And why is there a problem with the 'dataType: "json"' attribute?

Comment: A few notes.  `testobj = {...}` replaces whatever was in `testobj` with an object.  `dataType: "json"` is the data type of the data *returned* from the server.  You get an error because the server is not returning JSON, and jQuery is trying to parse it.

Comment: @RocketHazmat you should post as answer. spot on

Comment: Well, there you go! I think I'll take a break ... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing here is to realize what the `dataType` parameter is actually for.  It's used to tell jQuery what you are expecting to *receive* from the server.  You are getting an error because you told jQuery to expect JSON, but that's not what you are giving it.  It's trying to parse it and fails.  The data *is* being sent to the server.

Second, you are *not* sending JSON to your PHP script.  In both examples (which are the same, btw), jQuery is converting the object (not JSON [see note below]) to a query string and sending that via POST, just like a normal `<form>` POST would.

Third, your "array" creation.

```
var testobj = new Array();
testobj = {
  "test1":"test1data",
  "test2":"test2data",
  "test3":"test3data"
};
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  This creates a new array then immediately throws it away and uses an object instead (you are setting `testobj` to an object, same as the first example).  Note that arrays in JavaScript are numeric only, it does *not* have "associative arrays".

P.S. There is no such thing as a "JSON Object".  You are not using JSON anywhere in this code.  JSON is a *string representation* of data that has similar syntax to JavaScript arrays/objects.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

P.P.S. Don't use `.success()` and `.error()`, they are deprecated.  Use `.done()` and `.fail()`.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Thank you for learning me real good! :)

Comment: As I reflect on this ... I honestly don't see the difference between my "object" and a simple JSON "string". Could you enlighten me, please? Why is that not considered JSON syntax? (Info gleaned from http://www.json.org/, if I understood it.)

Comment: @JamesButler: JSON is a when it's is a string.  This is JSON: `var x = '{"your": "data", "test": [1,2,3]}';`  Notice how `x` is a string.  It just so happens to contain something that can be parsed into an object.  This might help: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Thank you. I got a bit confused by json.org which includes "object" as a valid JSON construct, much as I used, above. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @JamesButler: Think of that as what it gets decoded as.  `{}` gets decoded to an object.

Comment: Yikes! :) I'll probably stick with arrays for what I do, but I did find another problem with my code, JSON-wise, probably having to do with whitespace or something: If I break the line during the JSON string definition like I did above, but JSON-correct, I get an "Unexpected token: ILLEGAL" error at the line break, but if I keep everything on the same line, i.e. var str ='{"yadda":"yadda"}';, then it throws no error. So ... keep those JSON strings in a line, I guess. Back to the arrays. Thanks again. Learned a lot.

Comment: @JamesButler: In JavaScript, strings can only be single lines.  It doesn't support multi-line strings.